# Association on a list

Tags: associations

I have a dataset under this form : 
sentence = {sentence1, sentence2, sentence3,...}

and a list of label : 
label = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7...} both have same length !

So I want to make an association between my first and second list as sentence1 = label 1

So I tried this code

**ruleData = 
 Table[Rule[sentence,label], {i, 1, Length[sentence]}]**

so as when I recall ruleData[[7,1]], it should give me : sentence7 (as label7 is 7)

but my code is not working...
Any hints ?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `sentence[[i]]` etc in your table? p.s. check `AssociationThread[label, sentence]`

Comment: Thank you ! It works !

I want now to apply TFIDF to this variable ruleData and hence use this code :
 TFIDF = FeatureExtraction[ Join[First /@ Keys@ruleData[[All]], Last /@ Keys@ruleData[[All]]], "TFIDF"] 
but the output is telling me that there is nonatomic expression. As I wanted to apply the tf-idf for each sentence and for the total of sentences ...
Any ideas of how to solve it ?

Comment: You're pulling the `Keys` out of your association and then mapping `First` over it. Keys are usually atomic expressions (numbers, strings, etc.) and you cannot apply `First` and/or `Last` to atoms. It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do from a comment like this.

Comment: I want to apply TF-IDF:

puting the number of times that a word appears in a sentence (term frequency)
in relation to the number of times that that word appears in all other sentences
(document frequency) or in other words counting the times a word appears on a given sentence but reducing its importance if it appears on many other
sentences

Comment: To make an association, use `ruleData = AssociationThread[{sentence1, sentence2, sentence3}, {1, 2, 3}]`.  You may want to flip those around so can access `ruleData[3]` to return `sentence3`. To generate the TF-IDF, you can use GroupBy's to group documents, and words once they are tokenized/normalized. Please ask as a separate question with a minimal dataset.

Comment: Great, i create a new topic for the TF-IDF problem

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194822/words-weighting-with-tf-idf

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be fixed by supplying indexes to the variables bound to the lists.
Like so:

Contrived data

```
SeedRandom[1];
With[{n = 4},
  sentence = 
    StringJoin[#1, " ", #2] & @@@ Transpose@{RandomWord["Verb", n], RandomWord["Noun", n]};
  label = Range[n]];
```

Then

```
ruleData = Table[Rule[sentence[[i]], label[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[sentence]}]
```

gives

> ```
> {"beget weevil" -> 1, "closet clanswoman" -> 2, 
>  "panel seconder" -> 3,  "cauterize prominence" -> 4}
> ```

and

```
ruleData[[4, 1]]
```

gives

> `"cauterize prominence"`

as expected.

But there is a much better way. Mathematica has associations built-in a hash table objects. They are very efficient and make working with key, value associations very easy. Here is how you would set up and use an association for the contrived data.

```
 assocData = AssociationThread[label -> sentence]
```

You can retrieve the sentence that has 4 as it key by simply writing

```
assocData[4]
```

> `"cauterize prominence"`

Answer (score 0):

say your `sentence` as `lst`
your `lable` as `lbl`

Then

```
lst = {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7};
lbl = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

to combine or associate two list, then use

```
data=Flatten /@ Transpose[{lst, lbl}]

output (* {{s1, 1}, {s2, 2}, {s3, 3}, {s4, 4}, {s5, 5}, {s6, 6}, {s7, 7}}*)
```

To use Table to get specific list define

```
Table[data[[i]], {i, 1, Length[lst]}]
output (* {{s1, 1}, {s2, 2}, {s3, 3}, {s4, 4}, {s5, 5}, {s6, 6}, {s7, 7}}*)
```

To get list from 6 to 7 `== Length[lst]==Length[lbl]`

```
Table[data[[i]], {i, 6, Length[lst]}]

output(* {{s6, 6}, {s7, 7}} *)
```

To get specific list you can use above table or just use

```
data[[3]]

output (* {s3, 3} *)
```